# WordPress: Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am trying to use WordPress's core function `wp_remote_post` to post data into the server and get response back from there. I am fairly new to PHP and WordPress. When I am running the following code I get

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted
>   to string in
>   /var/www/wp-projects/csrvtool.com/wp-content/themes/yrc_csrvtool/ajax.php
>   on line 146

which is. this line:
`tt_platform_api_wordpress_request($url_send, $arr, 'helper/ping', 120);`

```
/**
 * Wordpress request handler
 * @param string $url
 * @param array $params
 * @param string $endpoint
 * @param int $timeout in seconds
 * @return object|string
 */

$url_send = "https://api.emailer.traveltime.com/v1/";

    $arr = array(
        'accessToken' => 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx',
        'username' => 'bob',
        'location' => array(
            'city' => 'Kansas City',
            'state' => 'Missouri'
        )
    );

    tt_platform_api_wordpress_request($url_send, $arr, 'helper/ping', 120);


    function tt_platform_api_wordpress_request($url, $params, $endpoint, $timeout) {
        if(!function_exists('wp_remote_post')) return FALSE;

        $response = wp_remote_post(
            $url,
            array(
                'timeout' => $timeout,
                'headers' => array( 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' ),
                'body' => json_encode( (object) $params )
            )
        );
        if( !is_wp_error($response) ) {
            return (object) array(
                'data' => $response['body'],
                'code' => $response['response']['code']
            );
        } else {
            return 'wp_remote_post returned an error for ' . $endpoint . ': ' . var_export($response, TRUE);
        }
    }
```

### Edit

I tried `var_dump ( (object) $arr );` which outputs the following:

```
object(stdClass)#546 (3) { ["accessToken"]=> string(36) "76A4412A-4737-4DB7-9098-4D4698FE895C" ["username"]=> string(3) "bob" ["location"]=> array(2) { ["city"]=> string(11) "Kansas City" ["state"]=> string(8) "Missouri" } }
```

What am I doing wrong and what is the right way of doing it?

Comment: edit your question to add the complet error message with the line number.

Comment: @mmm Added complete error message with line number.

Comment: @JordiNebot Tried your suggestion with no luck! :( Still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you confirm the posted code is from the file mentioned in the error? Cause it doesn't make sense to me...

Comment: Yes, the location of the error and the file where the code is in are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your post doesn't seem to show the part where you actually cast the object to a string.

Presumably you're doing something with the result of `tt_platform_api_wordpress_request` which is stdClass (when successful) according to your code. Perhaps you're echoing it, or concatenating it or passing it to some other function that treats it as a string. Your code doesn't show this.

Don't attempt to use a stdClass (or an array for that matter) as a string. Handle it as what it is.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are type casting response to object and then trying to access it as array. Remove (object) and use response as regular array. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! After removing type casting from (object) response now I am getting `Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/wp-projects/csrvtool.com/wp-content/themes/yrc_csrvtool/ajax.php on line 146
Array`.

Comment: Can you var_dump $response?